# How to edit the value in datasource (SampleData in Pentaho)

Tags: pentaho, saiku

Can anyone give me a suggestion how I edit the value in SampleData (The number,value in the table from picture in the link). Which file should I look into?

Thank You

[SampleData](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16645268/Capture.JPG)

Answer (score 0):

You can not edit sampleData directly, you can create your own JNDI Connection and visualize your own schema(Cube) in saiku.